# google maps fragment activity in Android Studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio

I have problem with importing google maps api in Android Studio. I created new project with Maps activity on api lvl 15, but in Android Studio all maps classes or method are red, but if i run this app on phone everything work correct. How can i solve this problem? I tried with official google tutorial.

```js
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

This is what i import.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Android Studio shows the red lines some imports at the Gradle point or so are missing;

By the way, **Android Studio** has an utility to create Google Maps Activities at:

> File > New > Google > Google Maps Activity

Comment: Create a **New Activity** by this way and everything should be right.