# Google Maps Activity error on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I created a Google Maps Activity on Android Studio but all the methods and classes imported are on red

[image]

i found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036723/google-maps-fragment-activity-in-android-studio) but it doesn't have a solution. 
what could be the problem of this?

Here is the whole class file, all the methods and imports are red

```
   package com.samplemap.dens.myapplication;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

Comment: rebuild your project and try again

Comment: Have you added Google Service Library in Gradle? If so, try Rebuilding the project. Or try "Invalidate Cache and Restart"

Comment: @NileshJarad i rebuilded my project but nothing happens

Comment: @Renges I dont know how to add Google Service LIbrary in Gradle

Answer (score 2):

Add dependency in your gradle and rebuild your project

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: can you give a solid instruction to do this? I'm totally new to android and android studio

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.todroid.com/how-to-create-a-google-map-application-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 1):

i encountered the same problem yesterday.
Do this:
1)Go to FILE and "Invalidate cache and restart"
2) Build your project.
Now,It will surely work!:)

Answer (score 0):

I am late and new to Android.
It happened to me and found the solution by checking my network(Ethernet properties).
Your network may be in limited.That is why the Gradle sync failed error occurs.